# Set mermaid.initialize property in Mermaid CLI

Tags: mermaid

When using [Mermaid](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/580) in the browser, one can set the `mermaid.initialize` property to alter the SVG produced:

```
mermaid.initialize({
    flowchart: { 
        curve: 'basis' 
    }
});
```

How does one set this property when using [Mermaid CLI](https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I would figure it out only minutes after posting!

The config should be put into a separate file using valid JSON (double-quoted keys and values):

```
$ cat mermaid-config.json
{
    "flowchart": { 
        "curve": "basis" 
    }
}
```

And the `mmdc` executable should be called with the `-c` flag:

```
$ mmdc -c mermaid-config.json -i foo.txt -o foo.png
```